# Battery management

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am currently charging a battery for a tablet with a Samsung charger. This charger can deliver up to **2A** (below I put a picture of this charger). I would like to indicate by two leds when the battery is charged or not. Then I found the charging module **TP4056-42** that manages the charging of the battery and indicates through the LEDs the charge. This module can provide up to 1A for the battery. I wonder if you have problems with the diagram below. Since the charger I will connect in the module supplies 2A and the module 1A. Diagram below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2friwFQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Samsung charger**

[image]

Comment: Did you actually have a question for us, or is this a dog and pony show? VTC.

Comment: Other than you're still an electrical engineering student. Practice is learning now. So yes, that's a question. For I do not have so much experience for the conviction and certainty of everything I do.

Comment: Your PSU needs to be rated for a higher current than the charging circuit will draw so the current ratings are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use TP4056 a module like this one:

[image]

Then yes that is how you would use it.

Connect USB to the input jack **or** connect a 5 V supply between IN+ and IN-

Connect the battery between BAT+ and BAT-

Done!

That's how I use these modules.

Optionally you could change the "122" resistor to change the charging current. See the [TP4056 datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Per the TP4056-42 datasheet, you can follow the application diagram and build a nice simple setup by feeding in 5V from your USB port to Vcc (see application circuit below).

[image]

The 2A should not be your concern as you will need to put a resistor in series with the voltage source.